# Django, how to modify output of a related model serizlizer?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

I have a model which has several `ForeignKeys`:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="staff", null=False, blank=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(to=Role, blank=False)
```

How do I use a fields from `Company` and `User` in `Employee` model? I need them for `__str__`.

Comment: `self.company.name`?

Comment: That works... But I've tried that and it didn't work :/

Comment: well here the assumption I made is that `Company` *has* a `.name` attribute. You can of course only refer to fields/properties/methods that exist at the `Company` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access these as attributes of the `self.company` or `self.user`, since `self.company` will return a `Company` object.

You thus can work with:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='staff'
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.company} {self.user.username}'
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: Thank you a lot. I missed the simplest solution :)